# Searching for images on the basis of latitude and longitude based proximity

Tags: image, search, flickr, geotagging

I want to make a flickr application which searches flickr database and look for images which are close to the latitude and longtitude that I give to the application.

Is such an application possible? If yes can someone point me to adequate pointers to start this.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.  Here is a tutorial: http://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch10s02.xhtml